# How to find my microphone name

Tags: 16.04, microphone, ubuntu-mate

I often record videos and I use simple screen recorder. But I recently got a new mic and I want to use that but I don't know the name of it and can't find it in the record audio tab. Any way to find the name of it without using command line? I can use command line if it is required to find the name of it though, I just prefer not to.

Comment: I believe the name of the microphone is irrelevant. Unlike other devices you can plug into your computer that vary and need specialized drivers, I believe a microphone simply has two or three leads that convert sounds to electrical signals and pass them to the computer, regardless of microphone manufacturer. Can you simply plug in the microphone and see if it works and then ask a question stating the problem if it doesn't?

Comment: I've already tested the microphone an it does work. My sound preferences call it: "Microphone" opposed to "Built-in Microphone". But Simple Screen Recorder shows no microphone simply labeled "Microphone". And I edit sound for a living I trust me I know how a microphone works. I just don't really know how Linux works.

Comment: Yeah I hate those built-in microphones on keyboards, I can't put masking tape over them like I can on the Laptop's built-in camera. Instead I take broken headphones, cut off the lead just after the jack and plug it into the microphone hole. Sorry for insulting your sound industry experience. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: No problem, it's an honest mistake.